# Why <ul> tag does not give any output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I tried this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.freesoft4down.com/Windows/System-Utilities/Clipboard-Tools/Page-1-0-0-0-0.html'
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
print soup.find('ul',{'class':'div_pages'})
```

I want to read the link inside the tag,so that I can open the next link inside it.
Because there is more than one page for each category.

Comment: The code gives the output: `<ul class="div_pages"><li class="actual"><span> ... </ul>'`

Comment: Do you know how to read and open the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get the URL of the next page, then you can use urllib2 to open the next page..etc.

To get the URL, you can manually build it if there is a clear pattern existing in the URL.

Or you can read the `next` tag to read the content.

```
# the advantage of using `Next` is it is web text based which is more reliable. 
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
url = 'http://www.freesoft4down.com/Windows/System-Utilities/Clipboard-Tools/Page-1-0-0-0-0.html'
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
print soup.find('ul',{'class':'div_pages'}).find(text=re.compile("Next")).find_parent('a')['href']
```

Output looks like:

```
http://www.freesoft4down.com/Windows/System-Utilities/Clipboard-Tools/Page-2-0-0-0-0.html
```

Now you have the link to the next page, and you just need to repeat this process if you want to get the next, next ... page.

Let me know if this has answered your question.

Comment: That is good but how can it can go to next page automatically without have to repeat one bye one manually?

Comment: @wanmohdpayed You are somehow really inventing the wheel. If there is any question considering how to collect url, it belongs to the scenario of "crawling", which should refer to some tools like "Scrapy" or "Nutch". You will be surprised how cool they are when you spend some time figuring out its syntax.. Scrapy is Python based. Good luck

Comment: Thanks @B.Mr.W. I can crawl everything based from your answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taking [B.Mr.W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941600/122661) and improving it to get the next pages one by one:

```
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_next_page(url):
    pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
    next_text = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'div_pages'}).find(text=re.compile("Next"))
    if next_text:
        return next_text.find_parent('a')['href']
    return None

next_url = 'http://www.freesoft4down.com/Windows/System-Utilities/Clipboard-Tools/Page-1-0-0-0-0.html'
while next_url:
    print 'Retrieving URL {}'.format(next_url)
    next_url = get_next_page(next_url)
```

You probably want to change the code so you actually do something useful with the pages.

For instance, you might want to put the `urllib.urlopen` call inside the `while` loop so you  can access the page's content directly. (And to prevent retrieving the page twice, you do not send the URL to the `get_next_page` function, but e.g. the content of the page.) But that all depends on why you are retrieving these pages in the first place.

Comment: Thanks man. I just got an idea from your code. How can I show the code here?

Comment: @wanmohdpayed Depends on why you want to show the code I guess. Is there something that's not working?

Comment: Thank @Mark van Lent! I got the code working properly.